# generating random numbers in equal increasing intervals

Tags: matlab

I'm going to generate uniformly distributed random numbers using rand() in MATLAB over X and Y axis. X range is 0:1:14 and Y range is 0.5:0.5:7 .
First, I tried to make N random numbers for each interval with the formula r = a + (b-a).*rand(N,1) (for a general case), and then appending each group of randomly generated data into a Z matrix.
The plot shows that I didn't generate the numbers correctly and don't know why this happens!

```
d=10;
k=0;l=1;
m=0.5;n=1;
Data = round(rand(13,15)); S = sum(Data(:));
Z = zeros(S,2);
num = 1;
[numRows,numCols] = size(Data);

for i =1:numRows
    for j =1:numCols
        if (Data(i,j)~=0)
        
%generate N random numbers in the interval (a,b)
%with the formula r = a + (b-a).*rand(N,1)        
        Z(num:num+Data(i,j)-1,1) = k + (l-k) .* rand(Data(i,j),1);
        Z(num:num+Data(i,j)-1,2) = m + (n-m) .* rand(Data(i,j),1);
        num = num + Data(i,j);
        end
    end
    k=k+1;l=l+1;
    m=m+0.5;n=n+0.5;
end    
plot(Z(:,1),Z(:,2),'+')
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I don’t understand the question. You state that you want to generate random numbers in two specific intervals, but the code you show does something very complex and very different. Why don’t you implement your formula directly? Please [edit] the post to clarify what you want to accomplish and why that plot shows you didn’t.

Comment: What I'm looking for is to generate random numbers for each interval. e.g. for x=0:1 and y=0.5:1, 10 random numbers, for x=1:2 and y=1:1.5, 6 random numbers, and so on.

Comment: You should start by setting up `X  = 0:1:14` and `Y = 0.5:0.5:7`. Then iterate your `i` and `j` to index those. Now generate random numbers within the interval `X(i)` and `X(i+1)`, and `Y(j)` and `Y(j+1)`.